# Graph Api updates for Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications, feed

I need to pull all the updated data (wall posts , photos in albums etc) from a facebook page to my application.
currently what I am doing is frequently polling the page wall feed and other non wall post objects(like albums ) and then save the updated fields. 
I'm using Graph API . 
I tried facebook real-time. But its not giving enough details.

Is there a way to receive notifications from pages via graph API once post or any object of the page get any update ?

Answer (score 0):

In theory this is now available through Facebook's [real-time updates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/), at least for wall posts and photos.  In practice, I'm having trouble getting it to work.